# What is best way to run multiple stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to run multiple stored Procedures which will return multiple result set(No Insertion).I've below approaches.Which will be faster & effective?

1. Run Multiple SP's asynchronously in One SP. Failing any SP should not affect other.
2. Execute multiple SP's asynchronously using C#.(Code Dependent)

Comment: "*which approach will be best?*" how do you define best, cpu cycles, memory, maintenance, speed, ease of reading, your dog likes it. pick the one you like and works for you

Comment: The first method is better. There will always be a connection lag between SQL server and your application server. So you'll be reducing that by only having one remote call.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple call your procedure one after other in individual `try catch` block, if want to do it in single procedure.

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[procedureName]
As
Begin

Begin Try
exec procedure1
End Try
Begin Catch
print 'Error'
End Catch

Begin Try
exec procedure2 
End Try
Begin Catch
End Catch

Begin Try
exec procedure3 
End Try
Begin Catch
End Catch
...

End
```

For asynchronous call of procedure you may use SqlClient asynchronous methods.

Comment: Can I run/execute it asynchronously?

Comment: You may find this link for more info about asynchronous procedure call. https://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/